# Concatenating and converting JCombo integer value to date

Tags: java, mysql, date, parsing, callable-statement

I read somewhere in MySQL reference pages that the `DATE` data type accepts either a date in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `YYYYMMDD`. So, either a `String` or an `int`

I have 3 JComboBoxes for day, month, and year.

So I converted them to `int`

```
int myDay = Integer.parseInt( dayJcbx.getSelectedItem().toString() );
int myYear = Integer.parseInt( yearJcbx.getSelectedItem().toString() );
int myMonth = Integer.parseInt( monthJcbx.getSelectedItem().toString() );
```

and tried to concatenate them as one `int`

```
int birthdate = Integer.parseInt(myYear+""+myMonth+""+myDay);
```

to match mySQLs format which is `YYYYMMDD` but still failed to insert it to the database. I get this message when I tried to insert April 3, 1987 as sample date.

[image]

Then I tried to use calendar class to add the `0` in month `MM` but still failed.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, myYear);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, myMonth - 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, myDay);
```

Please also tell me which is correct for inserting date through `CallableStatement` `cs.setDate(1,"date")` or `cs.setString(1,"date")`

I hope you can help me fix this because I'm now stuck just because of date. 
I recently tried `jodatime`.

By the way, my stored procedure looks like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `register`(
p_dateOfBirth DATE)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO registration(dateOfBirth)
    VALUES(p_dateOfBirth);

    COMMIT;
```

Comment: You should post your "insertion" code and tell us what the type of the column p_dateOfBirth is

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the description. p_dateOfBirth is an IN parameter of DATE type in a stored procedure.

Comment: Personnally, I wouldn't play with the integer format to pass a date to MySQL. This is really borderline and error prone, as you demonstrated with the missing 0. As a developer, I would have real difficulties following the line of thought. You've got a Date data type, why don't you simply use it? Integral types do not convey any sense of date, unless its for measuring a timestamp...

Answer (score 1):

As per your message

> ... value: '198743'

Definitively '198743' does not seem a date in `YYYYMMDD` format (8 mandatory positions), there are missing a couple of zeroes before `4` and `3` to get `19870403` what **is a correct `YYYYMMDD` format

Fast way (if your combos give `"04"` instead of `"4"` per April):

```
String myYear  = yearJcbx.getSelectedItem();
String myMonth = monthJcbx.getSelectedItem(); 
String myDay   = dayJcbx.getSelectedItem();

int birthdate  = Integer.parseInt(myYear+myMonth+myDay);
```

---

If you cannot change return result of combos, try this workaround

```
// pad the strings with 0, 2 positions mandatory
int myYear     = Integer.parseInt( yearJcbx.getSelectedItem().toString() );
String myMonth = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(monthJcbx.getSelectedItem()));
String myDay   = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(dayJcbx.getSelectedItem());

int birthdate  = Integer.parseInt(myYear+myMonth+myDay);
```

**DEMO:**

```
String myDay = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt("4"));
System.out.println(myDay);
```

**PRINTS:**

```
04
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this using **Java 8 DateTime API**

**Imports needed**

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

**Code:**

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(myYear,myMonth,myDay);
Date date = Date.valueOf(localDate);
cs.setDate(1,date);
```